# Updating af GridView - maybe a viewstate issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I am trying to update GridView with a lot of records through an ObjectDataSource. I am only updating the changed records, so I use ViewState to check if the original datatable has changed. It works fine on my localhost/IIS but when I try the same solution on the deployment server it gives me an error:

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

In this line of code:

```
Dim row As System.Data.DataRow = originalDataTable.Select(String.Format("ID = '{0}'", currentID))(0)
```

Below is an example of my code. Is there a problem with ViewState on the server?

```
Private ProdNum As String
Private tableCopied As Boolean = False
Private originalDataTable As System.Data.DataTable

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If Not tableCopied Then
            originalDataTable = CType(e.Row.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row.Table.Copy()
            ViewState("originalValuesDataTable") = originalDataTable
            tableCopied = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click, btnUpdate1.Click
    originalDataTable = CType(ViewState("originalValuesDataTable"), System.Data.DataTable)

    For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If IsRowModified(r) Then GridView1.UpdateRow(r.RowIndex, False)
    Next

    ' Rebind the Grid to repopulate the original values table.
    tableCopied = False
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Function IsRowModified(ByVal r As GridViewRow) As Boolean
    Dim currentID As Guid
    Dim currentNyhed as Boolean


    currentID = Guid.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys(r.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
    currentNyhed = CType(r.FindControl("CheckBoxNews"), CheckBox).Checked


    Dim row As System.Data.DataRow = originalDataTable.Select(String.Format("ID = '{0}'", currentID))(0)

    If Not currentNyhed.Equals(row("News").ToString()) Then Return True

    Return False
End Function
```

The GridView is bound to an ObjectDataSource with these basic settings:

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataByOverruled" TypeName="DSoverskrivslisteTableAdapters.Shop_Products_Egenskaber_OverrulingTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
```

The whole thing is based on this tutorial below. Instead of SqlDataSource I am using the ObjectDataSource which - as mentioned - works fine when run on my localhost, but gives me the error when uploaded to the deployment server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036(v=vs.90).aspx

Please help.

Comment: can I have code at where you are binding your gridview?

Comment: Hi - of course. I have provided more code and linked to the tutorial where I got the inspiration.

Comment: Hmm.. it's not a viewstate problem. I replaced the viewstate with a session variable, and it worked similar, ok local but not on server..